# Responsitive google visualisation datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-visualization

I have google visualisation datatable and work well, but my problem is with width of table.
When I click as I show on image I call function drawTable(); and then I get this:

[image]

and as you can see the table dont have width:100%;

But when I again click on "Mehanizacija" as you can see on the photo I again call function drawTable(); and then is all OK:

[image]

So what is the problem with datatable width... Why I need to call twice function drawTable() to work well? Any way to fix that? So with just one clikc to get datatable with width:100%... ?

Here is my function `drawTable();` :

```
        function drawTable() {


  // Create and populate the data table.
  var JSONObject = $.ajax({
                    url: 'call_radnici.php', // make this url point to the data file
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data:{ajdi:ajdi},
                    async: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                }).responseText;

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(JSONObject, 0.5);



        data.addColumn('string', '');
        for (var y = 0, maxrows = data.getNumberOfRows(); y < maxrows; y++) {
        var mc = data.getNumberOfColumns()-1;
data.setValue(y, mc, '<div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete this day data"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" ></i></div>');

        }


    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('tplradnici'));



    table.draw(data, {'allowHtml': true,  cssClassNames: {
        'headerRow': 'zaglavlje1',
        'tableRow': 'red',
        'oddTableRow': 'red',
        'selectedTableRow': 'orange-background large-font',
        'hoverTableRow': 'prekoreda',
        'headerCell': 'gold-border',
        'tableCell': 'cell',
        'rowNumberCell': 'underline-blue-font'}
    });

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the Table Visualization draws at 100% of the container div's width.  The pixel width of the container is fixed in the inline style of the `<table>` element (that is, if your container div is 500px wide, the `<table>` element will have `style="width:500px;"`).  The only reason I can think of for your Table to draw at less than 100% width on initial draw is if you are drawing it inside a hidden div (which breaks the Visualization API's dimensional measurements); this usually happens when the Table is drawn inside a tab interface.

Try adding a "ready" event handler for the table that changes the style of the internal `<table>` elements in the Table:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
    var tArr = document.querySelectorAll('#tplradnici table');
    for (var i = 0; i < tArr.length; i++) {
        tArr[i].style.width = '100%';
    }
});
```

Add the event handler to your code after creating the Table but before drawing it.